# What will be the stable versions to work with selenium automation with IE11 browser?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11, selenium-iedriver

Please let me know what will be best versions of the following to work with selenium automation with IE11 browser on a 64 bit machine.

Java

Selenium

IE webdriver

TestNG

Answer (score 1):

I am using these versions from 3 or 4 months and they are working fine :
Please download the latest IEDriver from https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/ and it will work with these versions.

Java version : 1.8

```
<properties>
        <testng.version>6.11</testng.version>
        <selenium.version>3.7.1</selenium.version>
    </properties>
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>${testng.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        </dependencies>
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Pretty effective Maven configuration.

Comment: @dengi13 Are you using eclipse? If so what version of eclipse are you using?

Comment: I am using Eclipse Oxygen December version

Answer (score 0):

Technically, all the versions of ***Selenium Clients*** (*Java*/*Python*/*C#*/*NodeJS*) are released only after the build successfully passes through certain types of tests (`alpha`, `beta`, etc). Moreover, the [Selenium - Build](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium#selenium--) section on [SeleniumHQ/selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium) clearly shows the *status* of the *current build* which is *Work In Progress*.

Hence to work with *Java*, *Selenium*, *IEDriverServer* and *TestNG* from stability perspective you can pick up any recent GA build. However as per *best practices* you should always upgrade your *Test Bed* with the current GA binaries. To be specific, as per current availability you can use the following combo:

- **`JDK 8u172`**
- **`Selenium v3.13.0`**
- **`IEDriverServer v3.13.0`**
- **`TestNG v6.14.2`**